# In R/plotly, how to change the tooltip number format?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

In R/plotly, how to change the tooltip format?
As below image, the tooltip 'Sales' show '0.230', how to transfer it to '23.0%' . Thanks！

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

mydata <- data.frame(
  category=LETTERS[1:5],
  sales=c(0.234,0.23,0.17,0.4,0.35)
)

p <- ggplot(mydata,aes(x=category,y=sales))+
  geom_point()

ggplotly(p,tooltip=c('y','x'))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try using `scales::percent`

```
library(scales)
p <- mydata %>%
  mutate(sales = scales::percent(sales)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=category,y=sales))+
  geom_point()

ggplotly(p,tooltip=c('y','x'))
```

[image]